# How can I get my two d3 graphs to appear next to one another?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to get these 2 divs called bar1 and bar2 to appear next to one another. I tried messing a little bit with the svg and div ids. Not sure how to get these two graphs to be side-by-side.

Here is bar1:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};

  var width = 360 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 330 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var chart1 = d3.select("#bar1")
     .append("svg")
     .attr('id', 'bar1svg')
     .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var svg = d3.select("#bar1svg");

  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
   y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = chart1.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +       ")");

 d3.csv ( "data/housingdata.csv", function(d) {
  d.median_housing_prices = +d.median_housing_prices;
  return d;
 }, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.neighborhoods; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return      d.median_housing_prices; })]);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(20, 's'))
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

   g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.neighborhoods); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.median_housing_prices); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.median_housing_prices); });

 });
```

Here is bar 2:

```
 var chart2 = d3.select("#bar2")
   .append("svg")
   .attr('id', 'bar2svg')
   .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    var g2 = chart2.append("g2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +   ")");

 d3.csv("data/housingdata2.csv", function(d) {
 d.median_housing_prices = +d.median_housing_prices;
 return d;
  }, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.neighborhoods; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.median_housing_prices; })]);

g2.append("g2")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g2.append("g2")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, 's'))
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

g2.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.neighborhoods); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.median_housing_prices); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.median_housing_prices); });
 });
```

Comment: This problem is not D3 related, but a simple CSS issue: set `float: left` for the divs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of d3 code there, obscuring the fact that you don't have a d3 or even an SVG problem, but a standard HTML / CSS layout issue.

Browsers try to position adajacent `<svg>` (and `<img>`) elements side by side, but then switch to a vertical layout if they judge the elements together as "too wide" for the current width. In CSS layout lingo, they have `display: inline` by default. `<div>` are block elements, however, so lay out vertically unless that is changed by CSS. The trick is subverting this, and insisting on the side by side layout, like so:

[image: grapical example]

Note the second `<svg>` is clipped by the window border, because you insisted on side by side layout, come what may.

All of the approaches to get this are HTML / CSS fixes. E.g.:

- Put the SVGs in adjacent table cells
- Use the `float` property to make the SVGs float left or right.
- Add a container `<div>` and absolutely position the SVGs therein.
- Add a container `<div>` and use text wrapping control to keep the SVGs side by side.
- Probably a half-dozen others.

Using a containing `<div>` with CSS property `white-space: nowrap` and then setting your SVG-continaing `<div>` elements to `display: inline` is an easy solution that nicely structures your HTML, yet is simple, reliable, and maintanable in ways the table, float, and absolute positioning approaches aren't. The quick and dirty formulation in your HTML follows. (It's neater to define the styling in your CSS file.)

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <div id="bar1" style="display: inline"></div>
    <div id="bar2" style="display: inline"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [running demo](https://jsfiddle.net/md634xh4/3/) of the idea.

The disadvantage to this "always go side by side!" command is, well, 
you may be successful. Then the elements are side by side always, even
if there isn't enough room for them to be fully displayed. If you don't want to be so always and forever, try a `float: left` style on `#bar1`, with very little
margins on your `<div>` and `<svg>`. In the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md634xh4/3/), you can change the window width to see this dynamc layout decision in action.

Comment: Belatedly noticed you're dropping SVG into DIV elements, so they need to have their display property set to inline. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @dancemc15 If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as such (by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer).